# Get PHP date automatically hour, minute and second but user selects day, month, year

Tags: php

I have a form field where a user can select the day, month and year however I would like to get the server hour, minute and second.

With my code

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_SESSION['form']['txtDate']))
```

produces `2013-04-27 00:00:00` where I would like `2013-04-27 16:30:55` for example.

Thanks

Comment: are you also storing hours minutes and second inside session.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['form']['txtDate'])) . " " . date("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you session does not storing hours,minutes and second then you can do this as below,

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['form']['txtDate'])) . " " . date("H:i:s")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['form']['txtDate'])) . " " . date("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use time() function it gives current time, with arguments Hi:i:s, see this for details. http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['form']['txtDate']` should have full format like `2013-04-27 16:30:55`